# Regarding the product price that goes into the cart along with the product

Tags: opencart

In backend admin panel following these steps: Catalog -> Products -> (I select the product I need) -> Edit -> Special. I insert the special price I want and it displays in Frond End in the product page. The Price which is in Data appears as CUT and the price I inserted in Special appears uncut. For example: [strike] 100.00[/strike] 90.00. My main question is: When I click Add to cart in the product page I want the the main price to go in the cart not the Special one. The client wants to see the special price but the price that goes into the cart to be the main price.

Many thanks

Comment: please upload proper screen-shot issue. i will chek it. and what is actual version of opencart ???

Comment: I have attached the image

Comment: upload admin side particular product price and special price screen-shot please

Comment: otherwise you can contact me personally. i will help you every time.

Answer (score 0):

Special Price is actually the discounted price of a product. So, if a product is of 100 then we can sell it for 90 on some festival seasons. That's when you should use special price. Regarding your specific requirement, you should either flip the values entered in special and base price (But the special price will now have strikethrough) OR you need to alter the code.